# terrraform code organization to distribute content

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am learning terraform.
I have my terraform code currently organized as  -

```
  main.tf
   ->modules
    ->route53
    ->network
    ->ec2
```

This works well for most cases but I now want to distribute the whole recipe of bringing up a server (ec2 with some programs i configured running) including the route53 domain name as a variable and subnets/security groups that are a resource in my network.
I have a lot of resources in the modules for route53/network/ec2 etc. etc.
Is there a good practice or pattern or one click command (like if i wanted to run just all the resources in the module network i could do)

```
target apply -f network
```

so can i do something like

```
terraform apply -target module.network.(resource) -target module.ec2.(resource) -target module.route53
```

etc etc.

Comment: You would declare only the `network` module in your root module config.

Comment: thanks but why would i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice to build Terraform code is to

> ... in most cases we strongly recommend keeping the module tree flat, with only one level of child modules, and use a technique similar to the above of using expressions to describe the relationships between the modules

From: [TF Module Composition guide](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html)

Basically this means:

1. Hold modules at other git or on same level folder as your non-module tf files (`provisioners`), make modules small and adhere to SRP (Single Responsibility).
2. Compose complex flow via module composition, having in mind DIP - [Dependency Inversion](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html#dependency-inversion)
3. Modules are single-responsibility abstractions, while `provisioners` are actual setups that compose module calls - on flat level, while later module calls may use outputs of module calls preceding them in the flow

This means :

```
- /modules
   - /vpc
     - vpc.tf
   - /subnets_private
     - subnets.tf
     - routing_tables.tf
   - /ecs_cluster
     - iam_ecs.tf
     - asg_ecs.tf
   - /network
- /provisioners
   - /staging
     - /workload_cluster_core_domain
         - main.tf
     - /control_plane_network
         - main.tf
```

Where main.tf have flat structure:

```
    module1--
             |    
  --module2<-  
  |   
  ->module3
```

Where each `module` can use outputs from:

- preceding (in dependency tree) `module` calls
- `data` calls.

Of-course you can partition your flows on state level but you will need to maintain it, or use OOS framework, a la Terragrunt, or write your own wrapper (quite common approach btw) - but that, obviously, will require wrapping TF cli usage in bash/go/python/node/etc.